# PHP explode not filling in array spot 0

Tags: php, explode

I have a file we will call **info.txt** under UNIX format that has only the following in it:

```
#Dogs
#Cats
#Birds
#Rabbits
```

and am running this against it:

```
$filename = "info.txt";
$fd = fopen ($filename, "r");
$contents = fread ($fd,filesize ($filename));

fclose ($fd);
$delimiter = "#";
$insideContent = explode($delimiter, $contents);
```

Now everything looks to be working fine except when I display the array I get the following.

```
[0] => 
[1] => Dogs
[2] => Cats
[3] => Birds
[4] => Rabbits
```

I checked the .txt file to make sure there wasn't any space or hidden characters in front of the first # so I'm at a loss of why this is happening other than I feel like I'm missing something terribly simple. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use $contents = file_get_contents("info.txt");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`explode()` splits on the delimiter. If there is nothing before the first delimiter, then that's what the first element will be. Nothing. An empty string.

Comment: Right. And to overcome this, I would suggest `$contents = trim($contents, $delimiter)`. :)

Comment: Wow I didn't even think about it that way. I got in the sense of after the delimiter. That explains it all. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that it's because the very first character is a delimiter, so it's putting whatever's to the left of it in the first element, even if it's an empty string. So you would have to start the file with "Dogs", not "#Dogs"

Answer (score 0):

You're running it like

> #Dogs#Cats#Birds#Rabbits

PHP splits it by cutting, thus where you have Dogs it sees it like 'Blank Space' | Dogs.

You can easily fill [0] by using [array_shift($input, 1);](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could explode by newlines and not use the # at all although then you would have a trailing empty item. I guess you still have to do some integrity check (remove the first/last item if empty) after parsing.

Answer (score 0):

another way

```
$f=file("file");
print_r( preg_replace("/^#/","",$f) ) ;
```

Comment: Well, your code would cause another issue: the trailing new line will be included in each array item. Use the flag FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES. Apart from that, It's pretty clever and elegant. Wondering which solution would perform best.